# Add condition in where clause in Oracle View

Tags: oracle, view, where-clause, case-when

I have below Oracle View which is working fine. But now i want to add combination of condition like below:

```
EUREX_ROOT <> ROOT
AND EUREX_ROOT = 'BAY'
```

So i want all the remaining data excluding the data with the above combination of condition but dont know how to achive this in this View.

In BB_IMPORT table field EUREX_ROOT is not present and i am using case condition to generate it so there might be issue with the alias here if we try to use this field in where condition.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW
    BB_IMPORT_TEST
    (        
        ROOT,
        EUREX_ROOT
    ) AS
    (
        SELECT
        ROOT,
        CASE
            WHEN exch_code IN ('EUX')                
            THEN ID_EXCH_SYMBOL            
            ELSE NULL
        END AS "EUREX_ROOT" from BB_IMPORT)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't that be

```
SELECT root, eurex_root
  FROM (SELECT ROOT,
               CASE
                  WHEN exch_code IN ('EUX') THEN ID_EXCH_SYMBOL
                  ELSE NULL
               END
                  AS EUREX_ROOT
          FROM BB_IMPORT)
 WHERE NOT (    EUREX_ROOT = ROOT
            AND EUREX_ROOT <> 'BAY')
```

Comment: i am getting error as EUREX_ROOT invalid identifier...problem is with the alias as in BB_IMPORT field EUREX_ROOT is not present...thats why i am using case condition to generate it

Comment: Aha, sorry. So you'd use current query as an inline view and apply condition to it. I edited my answer; have a look, please.